# LK Optical flow using OpenGL ES on iOS or Android

Tags: ios, opengl-es, computer-vision, opticalflow

Have anyone dealt with computer vision algorithms such as LK optical flow using OpenGL ES on iOS or Android platforms? It's hard for OpenCV to make it real-time, so is it possible for OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Brad Larson's GPUImage library?
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

There is no direct method to implement optical flows using this library like cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK in openCV, there is a motiontracker that you could use though. Alternatively,You should be able to set up your own pipeline using GPUImage library to do optical flows.
Cheers.